# What is the point of void operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, void

I've seen some people using `void` operator in their code. I have also seen this in `href` attributes: `javascript:void(0)` which doesn't seem any better than `javascript:;`

So, what is the justification of using the `void` operator?

Comment: void is a operator that returns nothing after evaluate a given expression, you dont need use "(" and ")" to make it work.

Comment: sizeof is the same in C -- but that code is much clearer if parentheses are used.

Comment: `void` is used infrequently. In ES5 it is considered obsolete. After evaluation of its operand it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The JavaScript, the `void` operator is used to explicitly return the undefined value. It's a unary operator, meaning only one operand can be used with it. You can use it like shown below — standalone or with a parenthesis.

```js
void expression;
void(expression);
```

Lets see some examples:

```js
void 0; //returns undefined
void(1); //returns undefined

void 'hello'; //undefined
void {}; //undefined
void []; //undefined

void myFunction(); 
void(myFunction());
```

If you ask why do you need a special keyword just to return undefined instead of just returning `undefined`: the reason is that before ES5 you could actually name a global variable `undefined`, like so: `var undefined = "hello"` or `var undefined = 23`, and most browsers would accept it; the identifier `undefined` was not promised to actually be undefined¹. So, to return the *actual* undefined value, the `void` operator is/was used. It's not a very popular operator though and is seldom used.

Let's see an example of function with `void`:

```js
//just a normal function
function test() {
    console.log('hello');
    return 2;
}

//lets call it
console.log(test()); //output is hello followed by 2

//now lets try with void
console.log(void test()); //output is hello followed by undefined
```

`void` discards the return value from the function and explicitly returns undefined.

You can read more from my tutorial post: https://josephkhan.me/the-javascript-void-operator/

¹ In ECMAScript 5 and later, the global variable `undefined` is guaranteed to be undefined ([ECMA-262 5th Ed.](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262%205th%20edition%20December%202009.pdf), § 15.1.1.3), though it is still possible to have a variable inside an inner scope be named `undefined`.

Answer (score 65):

[Explanation of its use in links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430349/what-does-the-browser-do-when-the-source-of-iframe-is-javascript/430359#430359):

> This is the reason that bookmarklets
>   often wrap the code inside void() or
>   an anonymous function that doesn't
>   return anything to stop the browser
>   from trying to display the result of
>   executing the bookmarklet. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> javascript:void(window.open("dom_spy.html"))
> ```
>
> If you directly use code that returns
>   something (a new window instance in
>   this case), the browser will end up
>   displaying that:
>
> ```
> javascript:window.open("dom_spy.html");
> ```
>
> In Firefox the above will display:
>
> ```
> [object Window]
> ```

Comment: See also [void operator MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void).

Comment: Internet explorer (I tested IE 11) is aligned with Firefox's behavior but Chrome is not for the JS code `javascript:window.open("dom_spy.html");`. It opens a new tab instead without any side-effect on the current tab window.

Comment: This is the original motivation for including the `void` operator in the language, [according to Javascript creator Brendan Eich](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2816/89).

Answer (score 40):

**The `undefined` value was not directly accessible in JavaScript until JS1.3.**

**An operator `void <expression>` was therefore included to permit access to this value.**

It is sometimes useful, particularly when working with the Web API (e.g. event handlers), to ensure that the result of an expression is consistently `undefined`.

When the `undefined` property was added to the global object in JS1.3 the utility of `void` became non-obvious.

Hence your question.

Comment: This appears to be apocryphal ─ [according to Javascript creator Brendan Eich](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2816/89), the `void` operator was added to the language for the purpose of discarding the value of a `javascript:` URL.

Comment: There is no such thing as ES1.3. How does this blatantly false answer get 38 upvotes?

Comment: You're dancing on the head of a pin about ES1.3 vs JS1.3?  Wow. https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/ch01s02.html

Answer (score 15):

Consider the following:

```
<a href="javascript:void(fish=document.getElementById('foo').value);void(document.getElementById('bar').value=fish);">With Void</a>

<a href="javascript:fish=document.getElementById('foo').value;document.getElementById('bar').value=fish;">Without Void</a>

<input type="text" id="foo" value="one fish" />
<input type="text" id="bar" value="no fish" />
```

The first link will swap the values of the text fields.  The second link will open a new page with the text "one fish".  If you use a `javascript: link`, the minute an expression returns something other than `null` or `undefined`, the browser will interpret that as what the link should do.  By wrapping all expressions/statments in a `void()` function, you ensure your entire snippet of code will run. These days, this is primarily of use in Bookmarklets, as using an `onclick` attribute, or setting up event handlers in separate Javascript blocks/files is the "norm".

As for `javascript:` vs. `javascript:void()`, the first statement is ambiguous. You're saying, "hey, I want to run some javascript", but then you don't provide any code. It's not necessarily clear what the browser should do here. With the second statement you're saying "hey, run some javascript", and your code eventually returns undefined, which the browser knows means "do nothing".

Since I'm here, I'll also point out that using either `javascript:` or `javascript:void();` has fallen out of favor with most people who care about markup.  The better thing to do is have your onclick handler return false, and have the link pointed towards a page/resource that makes sense for people who have javascript turned off, or are using a javascript blocker such as NoScript.

Comment: The question author wrote "javascript:;", not "javascript:". So, it wouldn't be ambiguous in that case, would it?

Comment: Does any empty statement return false, or does it return true, indicating the statement ran successfully?

Comment: Why would an empty statement return something?

Comment: Invalid syntax: `(...;...)`. Either use the comma operator, or place `void 0` or `void(0)` at the end.