# Why is Window.open()'s return type void?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

Doing something like this is perfectly permissible in javascript:

```
var newWindow = window.open(...)
```

However, this does not work in the senario of GWT (I am using 1.5 I dont know about later versions),

```
Window window = Window.open("", "", "");
```

Throws me a compile time error that the open is a method with a return type as void.

Why should it be void ? What if i want to close my popup from the main Window ?
how do I get its handle ?

I will have to resort to native javascript no doubt but i was just curious so as to why this is so...

Comment: any other solution thts applicable to me ?

Comment: Related post - [What is the point of void operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/666936/465053)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why GWT doesn't support what you're asking for but there is a [ticket](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=404)  requesting multiple window support where a number of workarounds are discussed in some detail.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I do fail to see any work arounds mentioned there, do take a look at my post there too...

Comment: forgive me on that comment, on closure inspection, i did see work around suggestions but no one has suggested a concrete solution yet
I am still pondering over how two seperate windows can exchange data using global javascript variables ??

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/b03558f44e3f0ccb/1f5f23effafa2f4f?lnk=gst&q=open+window+&rnum=2&pli=1 has a concrete solution. thanks for posted me to that bug, still open to solutions though

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not aware of a complete solution.  Hopefully someone else is though...