# who can give me explain it about javascript?

Tags: jquery, javascript

javascript:delete_reply_notify('14557174');void(0)

it make javascript delete one row which id = 1455174

but ,why is  void(0)?   what's mean ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666936/what-is-the-point-of-void-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its to prevent the default behaviour of the link from being activated, namely redirecting the browser to a new page. Your example though shows poor JavaScript practice - you should look into coding things [unobtrusively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and into the use of [progressive enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the page reloading upon a single click, we can use `JavaScript:void(0);` within the anchor link.

Answer (score 0):

stops the link activating. Best to avoid the javascript protocol if possible better to use the click event.