# javascript injection and looping

Tags: javascript, testing, code-injection

I want to test a site against javascript injection. I am familier with following syntaxes which are working fine.

```
javascript:alert(document.cookie);
javascript:void(document.cookie="authorization=true");
javascript:void(document.cookie="authorization=true");javascript:alert(document.cookie);
javascript:void(document.forms[0].email.value="test@test.com");
```

I tried following to inject a loop

> javascript:for(i=0;i<10;i++){document.forms[0].t1.value=i;}

It is working. But clering all the contents of browser and prints '9' (result).

Is there any way/sybtax to inject a loop so i can run/call a function/statement multiple times. Or any tool/utility/aadon which can help me.

*I can run the site only in IE.

Comment: It's nice to see someone that actively cares about javascript vulnerabilities. Cheers to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `void(0);` to the end of your code:

```
javascript:for(i=0;i<10;i++){document.forms[0].t1.value=i;}void(0)
```

However, you may want to move your code into a closure; you're modifying a global variable named `i`. Here we combine this with `void` as well:

```
javascript:void(function(){for(var i=0;i<10;i++){document.forms[0].t1.value=i}}())
```

Comment: wow great. it works thanks @icktoofay for quick reply. Can you sugegst me some link where i can read more about it.

Comment: @articlestack: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666936/).