# Can't understand why JavaScript void function is used

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the point of void in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666936/what-is-the-point-of-void-in-javascript)

At many places I have seen *Javascript Void*, but I am still not able to understand why this one is used. I am able to do complex javascript coding but not clear about this particular function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-tag-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: Also have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void.

Comment: **`void` is not a function!** It's an **operator**.

Answer (score 0):

void is an operator that is used to return a null value so the browser will not be able to load a new page.

//explain the code

```
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" ondblclick="alert('Well done!')">Double Click Me!</a>
```

In above ex nothing will happen on single click but if you double click it alerts Well done!
(void(0) used to prevent the page from loading)

Comment: Not a `null` value. It's an `undefined` value. Reloading the page won't happen magically, you're missing some explanation.

Comment: Even though both are considered falsy values `null == undefined`, they're still [different things](http://jsfiddle.net/sqUdN/) `null !== undefined`. [As you can see](http://jsfiddle.net/zeaEW/), the [void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) operator returns `undefined`, not `null`.