# What is the void in Javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the point of void in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666936/what-is-the-point-of-void-in-javascript)
>   [What does “javascript:void(0)” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean)

Everywhere I see this `javascript:void(0);` to do nothing I think. (instead of this `javascript:;` can be used I think)

And that day I see `javascript:void(x=document.getElementById('mytext').value);void(document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML=x);` code in the page.

My question is very simple, why void? What void does?

Comment: Please don't remove the automatically added text. The system adds it according to links provided by users. Both those links contain answers that can together answer your question here.

Comment: It's less about a duplicate question - and more about the fact that an existing answer could also answer your question here.

Answer (score 3):

[MDN documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)

> This operator allows inserting expressions that produce side effects
>   into places where an expression that evaluates to undefined is
>   desired.
>
> The void operator is often used merely to obtain the undefined
>   primitive value, usually using "void(0)" (which is equivalent to "void
>   0"). In these cases, the global variable undefined can be used instead
>   (assuming it has not been assigned to a non-default value).

Answer (score 2):

[`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) is an operator which returns `undefined`, although evaluation the following expression. The brackets are not needed.

In `javascript:`-urls it is used because any return value would overwrite the current document (like `document.write()`).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a sort of alternative to simply terminating the click even in jQuery for example.  When you attach a click handler to an anchor tag, you should always return false at the end of the handler -

```
$("#btn").on('click',function(){
  // make toast
  return false;
});
```

Returning false cancels any other actions that would have been executed by the event.

When you attach a `javasctipt:void(0)` to the `onclick` of an element, you are preventing that event from doing anything and leaving all the work to your JavaScript.

Comment: 'javascript:'-urls are assigned to the `href` attribute. `void 0` is like setting the default action to "nothing".