# What's a good use of void()

Tags: javascript

EDIT: To clarify: My question isn't concerned with how void is used but whether void can be really useful. I'm asking this because the way people seem to use it is very offputting...

The [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) for the `void` operator makes an example of the operator in use

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Click here to do nothing</a>
<a href="javascript:void(document.body.style.backgroundColor='green');">Click here for green background</a>
```

Not exactly the sort of way we handle click events nowadays.

Is there a place for `void` in this world? Can someone show me a good example of using void?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the point of void in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666936/what-is-the-point-of-void-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jakob shows some practical use cases of `void`. However as he mentions `void` is not really required, but I use it to test for `undefined`. I use it to create my own `typeOf` function:

```
function typeOf(value) {
    if (value === null) return "null";
    if (value === void(0)) return "undefined";
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(value).slice(8, -1).toLowerCase();
}
```

You may read why I do so [here](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.typeof).

Comment: +1 for showing good use of void. I'm guessing your using void in case the context is an old browser where undefined is mutable? EDIT: Thanks for pointing me to that site, havdn't heard of it before...

Comment: Guys, you missed the point of use case #1 in my answer. You dont need void for testing for `undefined`, because `(function(){}()) === void(0)`. So stating "void is not required, unless you wish to test for undefined" is plain wrong.

Comment: Yes sir, you are correct. It is more succinct. Does that make the statement in this answer correct? A newbie reading only this answer will think that `void` is required to properly test for `undefined`. It is not.

Comment: Btw, even if `void` was not built into the language it could be implemented in one line. `var void2 = function() {}`. It can be used like this `void2(0)` or like in the other example `void2(document.body.style.backgroundColor='green')`. It is a completely superfluous language construct.

Comment: I couldn't agree more - `void` is not __required__ to test for `undefined`. I'll change that. Mind removing your down vote?

Answer (score 5):

Use case #1, `void(0)`: If you want a reference to the real `undefined` (and not just the variable, because it can be overwritten) you don't need `void`. You can get it like this instead: `(function(){}())`.

Use case #2, `void(exp)`: If you want to execute code and then return `undefined`, you can of course do it by wrapping your code in a function: `(function(){ exp; return undefined; }())`.

So, no, we don't need `void`. It does nothing unique. It is shorter than the above solutions though, so if you prefer short and obscure code you could use it (but please don't).

Answer (score 1):

void is an operator that is used to return a `undefined` value so the browser will not be able to load a new page. An important thing to note about the void operator is that it requires a value and cannot be used by itself.

Example:-

```
 <a href="javascript: void(0)">I am a link</a>
```

Ouput:-

```
 I am a link
```

Comment: The `void` operator __expresses__ `undefined`. It doesn't __return__ `null`. It's an operator. Not a function.

Comment: Corrected and thanx for updating me :)

Answer (score 0):

the void(0) is used to return "undefined", you can write there just "undefined", and also dont use that javascript: in href attribute - because its so old and it will not work for users with javascript disabled, also if someone open this in a new window they will see something like javascript:showPopup(27);